# Looking to find a working download to view or change DTS

Tags: sql-server, enterprise-edition, dts

I am new to working with databases and have inherited some legacy internal applications. These applications rely on a job that run daily to import data from excel into a database to get new data into the application. This job is executes a DTS that imports this data into the database.

I am looking for a way to view this DTS and potentially bring it into something a bit more modern (SSIS from my limited knowledge but I am open to other options). Any help would be appreciated.

This is all using SQL-Server Enterprise Edition, version 15.0.4138.2.

Comment: Your database system is SQL Server, presumably?

Comment: Yes it is, I will update the question.

Comment: Can you also please tag which specific version of SQL Server? Adding which Edition (e.g. Standard vs Enterprise) to your post is also never a bad idea. Thanks!